# Merging inner arrays of indices if they contain the same content

Tags: ruby

I'm generating an array of grouped indexes.  The indexes are points within an array that meet my grouping requirements. For example I'm grouping indexes from a grid where things are horizontally "close" to each other.  This is kind of what I'll be working with.

```
[[0,1,2],[3],[4,5],[5,6],[7,8],[8,9]]
```

I would like to merge by common indexes.  So the result should look like.

```
[[0,1,2],[3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

It feels like it should be an inject :+ on pairs if any inner items match.  But I don't see the Ruby way to do this.

Comment: Does it work transitively? If there are `[1, 2]`, `[2, 3]`, `[3, 4]`, then that becomes `[1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: It is not clear what "points within an array that meet my grouping requirements" means.

Comment: No.  I need to keep the indexes separated for groupings between horizontal index matching (items that are close to each-other)... the non grouped are left for vertical matching later on.

Comment: "the **output** I have to work with" -- Isn't that the **input**, as far as this problem is concerned?

Comment: As far as this yes.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x.sort.inject([]) do |y, new|
  (((y.last || []) & new).length > 0) ? y[0..-2].push(y.last | new) : y.push(new)
end.map(&:sort)
```

Comment: This works perfectly as long as my order is sequential. Throwing in `.shuffle` on the array breaks this.  This is a good answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. `x.sort.inject([]) { |y, new| ((y.last || []) & new).length > 0 ? y[0..-2].push(y.last | new) : y.push(new) }.map{|i|i.sort}`  Please update your code to match this and I will accept yours as the right answer.

Comment: As you wish!  I'm glad we found a functional-style solution.  You might want to modify your example to make the sorting requirements clear.  For example, you might want to start with `x.map(&:sort).sort` instead of just `x.sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing Ruby, there's probably a more concise way to do this, but this should give you what you want:

```
foo = [[0,1,2],[3],[4,5],[5,6],[7,8],[8,9]]

foo.inject([]) {|result,element|
  if (result and existing = result.find_index{|a| !(element & [*a]).empty?})
    tmp = result[existing]
    result.delete_at(existing)
    result << (tmp | element).sort
  else
    result << element
  end
}.sort
```

Output:

```
=> [[0, 1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

**Logic:**

For each `element` in the original array, check the newly-built array-so-far (`result`) for any entry which contains any of the same numbers as the next element using array intersection -- `!(element & [*a]).empty?` ...

- if found, remove said entry from the `result`, union it with the new `element` from the original array -- `(tmp | element)` -- then add it back to the `result`
- if not found, simply concatenate the `element` from the original array to the `result`

Comment: Note: Minor edit made to original answer, specifically `find_index` logic now handles out-of-order input, eg `[[0,1,2],[3],[5,6],[7,8],[4,5],[8,9]]`.

Comment: Yes. That works well. I'll need to add sorting to the inner arrays as the order is important. I tested this by putting shuffle on foo before inject `foo.shuffle.inject` and it does indeed join the correct ones.

Comment: Isn't assignment within an if statement considered taboo?  (Since it's most often misread.)

Comment: Good call re: sort -- I've updated the answer to include that as well, to avoid having it lost in the comments. As for the assignment in the if statement, I'm not sure -- it's an extremely useful pattern I've seen to check for the existence of a thing and grab it into a variable in one fell swoop, rather than `tmp = result.find_index(...); if tmp ...`

Answer (score 1):

Someone might find a more compact method, but this works...

```
array = [[0,1,2],[3],[4,5],[5,6],[7,8],[8,9]]
(0...array.length).each do |a|
  (a+1...array.length).each do |b|
    unless array[a].to_a  & array[b].to_a == []
      array[a].push(array[b]).flatten!.uniq!.sort!
      array.delete_at(b)
      b -= 1
    end
  end
end

p array
=> [[0, 1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: This works even with a shuffled array state.  Good work.  The inner arrays are unsorted.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions so far seem overly-complicated to me. I suggest this (assuming each element of `arr` is non-empty and contains only integers):

```
arr = [[0, 1, 2], [3],
       [4, 5], [5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9], [9, 10], [10, 11],
       [12, 13], [13], [13, 14]]

arr.each_with_object([]) do |a,b|
  if b.any? && b.last.last == a.first
    b[-1] += a[1..-1]
  else
    b << a
  end
end
  #=> [[0, 1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
```

You could alternatively do it by stepping through `arr` with an enumerator:

```
enum = arr.each
b = [enum.next]
loop do
  a = enum.next
  if b.last.last == a.first
    b[-1] += a[1..-1]
  else
    b << a
  end
end
b
```